# How to launch app automatically on alarm notification?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

I am developing an app which has a feature to set an alarm and on alarm time local notification will be fired.

is it possible to open an application on local notification event without having a user interaction?

Comment: apple doesn't provide this facility. you have to click on notification for launch application.

Answer (score 1):

Without user click on UIAlertView's button you can't open app. It's not possible.

Comment: No. not at all. User have to click on the UIAlertView button to launch the app.

Comment: If this answer is helpful to you then please accept the answer so that it will also help to others. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least not on a non-jailbroken handset. The closest, as you've already found, is with local notifications.